# Python Pandas loc key errors

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to print rows by label. But it kept giving me key error msgs.
My code is as following:

```
import pandas as pd

temp = pd.read_csv("Temperature_change_Data.csv")
print(temp.loc['KOR'])
```

I installed python 3 and pandas. I'm a beginner in a data science class. All other code I learned so far worked. Only this is giving me problems, and I can't figure out why. The data set was found on Kaggle 2 days ago. It was put in the same folder of the python project. If anyone can tell me what is wrong and how to fix it, it will be great! Thank you ahead.

Comment: Try `temp.loc[:, 'KOR']`. All rows of column KOR. You can also do `temp.loc[:, ['KOR',]]` to  return a dataframe

Comment: 'KOR' is a row label, not column label

Comment: Then check for white space

Comment: There is no white space

Comment: What is the output of `"KOR" in temp.index`?  If it’s not on your index, you cannot use loc to access it. Make that column to index to allow accessing

Comment: How to make that column to index??

Comment: `df.set_index('NAME_OF_COLUMN')` were NAME_OF_COLUMN is the column containing the value you are looking for. Another solution could be filtering your data with fields were `KOR`, you could do `temp.loc[lambda d: d['COLUMN_NAME'] == 'KOR']` COLUMN_NAME is the name of column that has value 'KOR'.